# Use changed values in other page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a textfield:

```
Voornaam: <h3 class="title1">Kevin</h3>
      <input type="text" id="myTextField1" />
      <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change1()"/><br/>
```

I can set a value of this using this function:

```
function change1(){
   var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField1').value;
   if( myNewTitle.length==0 ){
       alert('Write Some real Text please.');
   return;
   }
   var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('title1');
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles,title => {
    title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;
   });
}
```

Now in my other page, I want to use the value. I know I can for example pass a value from one page to another like this:

```
<a href='convert.php?var=data'>converteren.</a>
```

And then for example show it by doing this in the other page:

```
echo $_GET['var'];
```

But I cant really seem to figure out how to use the value which I've set using my textfield.

So my goal for now is to display the value I've set using my textfield in the other page using the method I just described.

Basically all I want to happen is for my textfield to change the value inside here aswell:

```
<a href='convert.php?var=data'>converteren.</a>
```

So where data is the value, I want it to become what I've put in the textfield.

Could anybody provide me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered a bit your javascript code to make the link as you want.

To explain the answer, i've added `document.getElementById("myLink").href="convert.php?var=" + myNewTitle ;` which updates your a href while your function runs and is not empty.

```
function change1(){
   var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField1').value;
   if( myNewTitle.length==0 ){
       alert('Write Some real Text please.');
   return;
   }
  document.getElementById("myLink").href="convert.php?var=" + myNewTitle ; 
   var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('title1');
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles,title => {
    title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;
   });
}

<a id="myLink" href='#'>converteren.</a>
```

Comment: That does however not use the method I described and does not pass the value to another page.

Comment: thats all you need to read the variable from php. From what I understand you dont get the URL correctly, so please show us your <form action> url.

Comment: You might misunderstand my question. I want my textfield to set the value in this: <a href='convert.php?var=data'>converteren.</a> So where data is the value now. I want to use my textfield to change that value or set that value. That's all.

Comment: @KevinBosman i've changed the code, please try and see if it cover your needs

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your inputs inside a [form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) element.

In the action attribute, specify the destination url.

In the method attribute, choose between [GET and POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

For example:

```
<form method="GET" action="convert.php">
    <input type="text" id="myTextField1" />
    <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change1()"/>
</form>
```

Clicking the submit button will call "convert.php?myTextField1={value}".